# Django, i would like to sent data from drop down menu to database when once the hit submit button but error occure

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to send data to the database from the dropdown menu from index.html that is why I have created models.py as the initial class named as Program and later on used it to Contact class using ForeignKey. registered Contact at admin.py and later on i have used class name programs to in index.html and it is rendering the name of the programs which is entered by me at admin panel of django. but the issue is {{program2}} does display at the index page but when user go the form and selects and submits this program2 data is not going to the database. How could i use the dropdown to sent value to the database. Help appreciated, accepting to resolve it from my way.

**models.py**

```
class Program(models.Model):
    program1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')


class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    address = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default='')
    program2 = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    # program = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    # bba = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    # bhm = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    w3review = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        contact = request.POST.get('contact', '')
        address = request.POST.get('address', '')
        program2 = request.POST.get('mba', '')
        # bba = request.POST.get('bba', '')
        # bhm = request.POST.get('bhm', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        w3review = request.POST.get('w3review', '')

        if name and contact and address and email and w3review and program2:
            contact = Contact(name=name, contact=contact, address=address, email=email, w3review=w3review, program2=program2)
            contact.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Enter all details")



        
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

**index.html**

```
<label for="cars">Choose Program:</label>
   <select name="cars" id="cars">
     
     <option id="mba" name="mba">{{program2}}</option>
     <option id="bba" name="bba">BBA</option>
     <option id="bhm" name="bhm">BHM</option>
    
   </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add program2 to the contect dict to have it available in your html
Like

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'program2': program2})
```

For the submit problem you need to post the complete form in your index.html

Comment: UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'program2' referenced before assignment   -- getting error

Comment: You set program2 only if it is a POST request ... possibly you send a GET request.

Comment: Could you please forward me complete code it will really help me